# Get master of one remote repository into master another remote+ one

Tags: git

I have two remote repositories (Say A and B). A has similer master (content wise)to B, but not the same.

I want to update A from B, so that A has same master like B. I want to kind of force update A from B so that master of A is same as B. What I'll do is as follows.

1.fetch master of B to my local.

2.Push this to B.

But I am not sure this is the best way or even the right way to do it

**Update**: It is just a one time activity. I need not to keep in sync both all the time

Comment: It's possible using a post-commit hook (look it up). Invoke repository A to pull from B once B gets updated, and vice versa.

Comment: Updated the question..Please refer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're looking for - a one-time conversion, as opposed to continuous integration - this should work out. It's a bit overkill, as you could adapt it to work in your currently existing local repo, but then I'd have to make assumptions about the current state of your local repo, and this approach will help avoid conflicts due to uncommitted changes, unpushed state, etc.

```
git init newrepo                                   # create a new scratch space repo
cd newrepo
git remote add originA <url or relative path of A> # add both original repos as remotes
git remote add originB <url or relative path of B>
git fetch originA master                           # fetch the branches we want
git fetch originB master
git checkout -b newbranch originB/master           # start a new branch from B's master
git merge -s ours originA/master                   # merge A's master in, but ignore
                                                   # the content, so the result is
                                                   # exactly B
git push originA newbranch:master                  # push the new merged head to both
git push originB newbranch:master                  # original repos
```

After this, you can get rid of the temporary repository, go back to your normal working repo, and `git fetch`/`git pull` the updates there. At this point, A and B have been merged together, but the content is exactly what B was, and both the original repos have been updated with the merged result (and the A repo is in a sense redundant, at least for its `master` branch; if there isn't any other work going on in it, it can probably be cleaned up, too). Another way of saying that is that your B repo now contains the full history of both A and B, in case you ever need to refer back to A for some reason, but A has essentially been discarded in favor of the development of B.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull from one and overwrite the other using a force push.

```
$ git pull A master
$ git push B master -f
```

In general force pushing should be avoided because you are deleting all the history and potential difference that are in the branch that you force pushing to.